# 9V SMD "terminals"

Tags: batteries, pcb-design, surface-mount

I intend to build my own USB rechargeable 9V battery,  [kinda like this one.](https://www.akkushop-austria.at/media/image/e3/bc/a9/Trustfire-9V-Block_600x600.jpg)

My main issue with those is that they usually use 2 Li-Ion batteries in series, which produces an insufficient voltage for my application.

So I've created my own version with an integrated boost converter, I'll see if the noise is low enough, otherwise I guess I'll have to add a linear regulator, and consistently overshoot with the boost converter.

I'd love to fit the terminals for the battery on the backside of the PCB, because it has pretty much the same size as the top/bottom side of a 9V cell, and the backside of my PCB is empty anyways. The issue is, I can't find any.

Comment: You can find them in every 9V battery. Take some discharged one and tear it apart.

Comment: I suggest using through hole components. Somone in an answer or comment linked to a digikey part made by Keystone. Here is a link to Keystone's website showing some right angle through-hole 9V style battery contacts. https://www.keyelco.com/category.cfm/9-Volt-Battery-Contacts/To-Mount-9V-Battery-On-PC-Board/p/404/id/422/c_id/692

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably enough force from detaching the terminals to rip off a SMD connector, which is why you can't find any.  Something like this:
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/keystone-electronics/967/36-967-ND/2745660
could be connected with through-holes to the component side of your board from the other end.

Comment: Agree. Keystone's website is keyelco. https://www.keyelco.com/category.cfm/Battery-Coin-Cell-Holders-Contacts-Clips/9-Volt-Battery-Contacts/p/404/id/422

Comment: Thanks to both of you! The right angled ones don't quite fit my design, but I think I can make the throughole ones work! With a bit of luck I might even find an Eagle library with it

Answer (score 0):

There are leaf contacts which have SMD versions. This requires your enclosure to properly support the battery.
[Leaf contacts on Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/battery-products/battery-holders-clips-contacts/86?FV=-8%7C86&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=Leaf%20contact&pageSize=100&pkeyword=Leaf%20contact)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find 9 volt battery connectors with wire leads at any hobby electronics shop.  Amazon sells a pack of 10 for C$8.00.  You will have to swap polarity if you use one of these on a power source rather than on a load.